# Search field is turning up empty when I search the Giphy API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been using the Giphy API, trying to get my Giphy app to work. Whenever I send a search to the Giphy API my search is turning up empty. Even when I have input something in the search field. I've `console.log()` everything and the console tells me that my search parameters come out empty. Not sure why whatever I am executing in the search field isn't being sent to the API.
Here's some Javascript code:
    
    ``` ``let giphySend = $("#giphySend");
     let giphyInput = $("#giphyInput")
       .val()
       .trim();
     let giphyHeader = $("#giphyHeader h1");
     let giphyAPIKey = "GET A GIPHY API KEY";
     let giphyInputArray = [];
     $(giphySend).on("click", function() {
       event.preventDefault();
       let url =
         "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=" +
          giphyAPIKey +
         "&limit=5&q=" +
         giphyInput;
       ``fetch(url)
         .then(response => {
           console.log(response);
           return response.json();
         })
         .then(json => {
           console.log(json);
           console.log(json.data); ```
         })

```
     .catch(err => console.log(err));
 });
```

sorry the formatting is being a little weird.
Here's some HTML:

```
  `<aside id="aside">
      <input
        type="search"
        placeholder="Search Giphy..."
        id="giphyInput"
      /><input type="submit" value="Send Request" id="giphySend" />
    </aside>
    <script src="assets/javascript/app.js"></script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define `let giphyInput = $("#giphyInput").val().trim();` outside your click event, so when you run the click event `giphyInput` is null because at the time the live runs the input is null.

Solution:

```
$(giphySend).on("click", function() {
let giphyInput = $("#giphyInput").val().trim();
```

Move the input into the click event.

Comment: awesome, thank you. I guess I thought because I named it outside in the window that it being global wouldn't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you are doing is you are taking value from the search box when your scripts or the webpage loads, so intially giphyInput = ""; and when you are clicking the search button it still an empty string. 
**You have to tell jquery to fetch the latest value from DOM.**

so in your on("click") callback function do this.

`$(giphySend).on("click", function() {`

```
`event.preventDefault();`

`//tell jquery to give latest value`
```

`giphyInput = $("#giphyInput").val().trim()`

```
`//Rest of your code with fetch function`
```

`}`